# What unit does Spatialite's Distance() function return?

Tags: sqlite, gis, distance, spatialite

[Spatialite](http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite/) has a the ability to calculate the distance between 2 geometries with it's [Distance()](http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.4.0/spatialite-sql-2.4.html#p13) function. There are other [functions](http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.4.0/spatialite-sql-2.4.html#p6) that work on LINESTRINGs. However I can't find out what units it returns it in. Is it metres? If I have 2 points, how do I calculate the distance between them in a spatialite query?

(For the record I'm using SRID 4326, i.e. WSG 86, i.e. the old traditional degrees of latitude and longitude).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the unit returned by ST_Distance(), ST_Length() and ST_Area() 
exactly is the one defined by the corresponding SRID.

consequently, if you are using latitude and longitude (SRID=4326, 
WGS 84), any length will be measured in DEGREES, and any area in 
SQUARE DEGREES.

if you are interested in giving a more conventional
unit (METERS, SQUARE METERS), you simply have to project
your geometries into some appropriate 'planar' CRS (e.g. UTM)
using ST_Transform()

Comment: Could you give an example of how to do this conversion in a function/expression?

Comment: @Rory Each degree latitude is exactly 60 nautical miles apart. That's 111,120 meters or 364,567 feet. Just multiply the value from Distance() with 111,120 to get the distance in meters.

Comment: @Phil I would expect that the latitude of each degree (in meters, miles etc.) depends on the geographic longitude and latitude (since the earth is not a perfect sphere).

Comment: @Lefteris Distance between each degree longitude varies depending on your geographic location, but distance between each degree latitude [remains a constant 60 nautical miles](http://geography.about.com/od/learnabouttheearth/a/nauticalmiles.htm). The important thing is the conversion ratio between latitude degrees and meters. Once you know that, you can apply it to the output of Distance().

Answer (score 0):

In version 2.4.4 and higher there is a function PtDistWithin() which returns meters for a distance query. See doc. section "SQL functions for distance relationships":
http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.4.0-4/spatialite-sql-2.4-4.html#p13